# Time Ago undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datetime, time

I'm using a function `prettyDate()` below to convert a timestamp into a more friendly format. I do not need a plugin that automatically converts the value in a div into a "Time ago" format.

An API returns timestamps `1400564166115` and `1400695785000`. `date.now()` gives `1400696094406`.

Using the code below, the first timestamp `1400564166115` gets converted to `2014-05-20T05:36:06.115Z`, where function `prettyDate()` turns it into `Yesterday`.

For the second time stamp, `1400695785000` converts to `2014-05-21T18:09:45.000Z`, but `prettyDate()` turns this into `undefined`. Additionally, `day_diff` is `-1` in this case. `diff` is `-14347.209` and slowly moving towards 0.

Why is it giving `undefined`, what caused `day_diff` to be `<0`?

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/pWNrS/

**Example**

```
var d = new Date(parseInt(1400564166115)).toISOString()
prettyDate(d)    // Yesterday

var e = new Date(parseInt(1400695785000)).toISOString()
prettyDate(e)    // undefined *****WHY?*****
```

**prettyDate()**

```
prettyDate = function(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}

// If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
        });
    };
```

---

**Stepping through prettyDate()**

date: `Wed May 21 2014 18:35:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)`

(new Date()).getTime():  `1400697389253`

date.getTime():  `1400711746000`

diff:  `-14356.757`

day_diff: `-1`

Comment: is it hitting your `if ( isNaN ??

Comment: @Pogrindis Yes, `day_diff` is returning `-1`, but I cant figure out why...

Comment: T'would be cool to see a jsfiddle of this

Comment: @geedubb Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pWNrS/

Comment: Second one returns "1 hour ago" for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZBhZ/

Comment: @geedubb Using your Jsfiddle, For me it returns `Yesterday` followed by `undefined`

Comment: me too.. : 
d:  Yesterday (index):54
e:  1 hour ago 

I have seen this before.. will need to check

Comment: Maybe it has to do with my computer? I'm using Chrome (v34.0.1847.137) on Mac OSX Mavericks. On another Windows 8 system with Chrome (also v34.0.1847.137), also getting `Yesterday` and `undefined`

Comment: I'm on Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137 Win 8.1

Comment: what about stepping through the code in your chrome.. i cannot reproduce the problem! :/

Comment: Tried it in IE11 for a "laugh" and it shows `undefined` in both cases

Comment: try using Math.ceil.. if your value is 0.n diff Math.Floor will return -1

Comment: Could it be related to browser culture?

Comment: @geedubb Updated OP with the various variable values as we step through the code...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/swH9mmm.jpg .. Im out of ideas.. ;( Sorry!

Comment: Maybe theres another "time ago" JS library that converts a timestamp to a "time ago" format? All I find are those that convert the value in a DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

The problem has to do with loss of timezone information.

When you mutate the ISO string, you're changing assumptions about the date/time being parsed. In the ISO format, the 'Z' indicates that the time given is UTC. However once you strip that out, the date parser no longer has any clues about what time zone to use, so it uses the local time zone and adjusts the time accordingly. This is what causes your `diff` to be negative (because of your local timezone offset).

A quick fix would be to append ' GMT' to the end of your date/time string before you pass it to `new Date()`: `new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ") + ' GMT')`. That is assuming that all dates passed in are UTC/GMT. However, if the browser supports ES5 (e.g. you could test `var supportsISO8601 = Date.prototype.toISOString === 'function';`, you can just keep it in ISO8601 format and pass the string directly to `new Date()`.